# Removing push notification crashing app

Tags: push-notification, sencha-touch-2, google-cloud-messaging

I have created an app in Sencha Touch 2 with GCM plugin. Everything working fine with push notification but when clearing notification, its killing app.

I have no idea of java, but still tried to fork GCM java code but didn't got any success by the solutions found after googling around,

Few solution(google gave ;) ) tried but no success:
- ExceptionHandling
- onResume() function

After researching lot, found onResume isn't getting even called and app is killed much before. I dont know how to debug it. Using cordova to build & webstorm IDE. 
Some saying less memory space might kill app but after testing on many devices found memeory isn't the issue.

Plz help me out as already wasted much time on it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what is wrong here, but as per you mentioned I am guessing the problem is with the handling of the event when the notification is clicked in order to open the subsequent activity. Please have a look at this code.

```
 @Override
   protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
       mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
           this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
           new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class), 0);
       NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
           new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
               .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
               .setContentTitle("New Message!");
       mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
       mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
       GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
   }
}
```

Please make sure you implement the onHandleIntent() method after the notification is tapped so that it opens the activity where it should actually be.